# Ajax call on asp.net page webmethord return Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Ajax call returns a Object object but can't read the data, and it's giving 
undefined error.

```
    function GetGooleMapnew()
    {           
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("Default.aspx/GetQueryInfo") %>',                
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                //var datas = data.hasOwnProperty("d") ? data.d : data;
                //alert(datas.TempId);  //Changed here
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            failure: function() { alert("Uh oh"); }
        });
    }
```

When I add this conversion JSON.stringify(data) this returns Authentication error came:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

How can I sort out this issue?

Comment: Try changing `data: {},` to `data: JSON.stringify({}),`. Also, share the server side code

Comment: Show your server side function

Comment: Its working fine after i commented the //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;

Comment: Again i am facing one big problem as i am not able to loop through the value retured as json

Comment: {
   "d":[
      {
         "__type":"_Default+Properties",
         "propertyid":"18",
         "state":"TamilNadu",
         "district":"RAMANATHAPURAM",
         "taluk":"KADALADI",
         "villages":"ORIVAYAL",
         "latitude":"9.240044",
         "Longitude":"78.520514"
      }]}